# Django: How to get all instances in a dynamic recursive relationship?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model which is defined as:

```
Model A:
   parent = ForeignKey('self')

Model B:
   a = ForeignKey(A)
```

Suppose I have some data defined with undefined level of A.

```
A1
|->A2
   |->A4->B1s
   |->A5->B2s
|->A3->B3s
...
```

If I have one of the A, how can I get all Bs related to it.

For example, how to get B1s and B2s, given A2.

How to get B1s, B2s, B3s from A1.

Answer (score 2):

The data structure what are you looking for called "[Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure))"
Django has few good implementation of it: [django mptt](https://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/tutorial.html) and [django treebeard](https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/docs/tip/#).

To answer exact your question:

- > how to get B1s and B2s, given A2. > `B.objects.filter(Q(a__a=a2))`
- > how to get B1s, B2s, B3s from A1.. > `B.objects.filter(Q(a__a__a=a1) | Q(a__a=a1))`

You can even add simple(silly) method to A model with recursion:

```
def get_all_children(self):
    result = []
    for child in B.objects.filter(a=self):
        result.append(child.get_all_children())
    return result
```

Django orm doesn't have recursive queries from the box, and i'm strongly recommend to use django mptt or treebeard.

Comment: mptt and treebeard, which one do you think is better. I think they are both great.

Comment: Looks like treebeard has a dump_bulk which is so cool. While, both of them don't have a method to get all the leaves, which is not so good. So I have to query all the nodes to get all Bs?

Comment: @crash843, the recursive function is almost correct. You need to add something to the list. Otherwise you will get an empty list every time.